# How can I use where function using insert into module

Tags: vb.net

My command is error in my sql command where clause, how can I handle it? any suggestion or any help?

This is my Error:
syntax to use near 'WHERE controlNumber = '' at line 1

```
cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO alamnotice (correctivePreventive) VALUES('" & Trim(txtremarks.Text.TrimEnd()) & "') WHERE controlNumber ='" & Trim(Form1.txtcontrolNumber.Text.TrimEnd()) & "'", con)           

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: `My command is error in my where module` <--- this is totally unclear. Please change your wording, maybe that will help. What are you trying to do? Let's say you did not post any code, how would you put the question?

Comment: Disconnect what?  Connect what?  I think your missing a using statement or something.  What error are you getting?

Comment: you should read up on SQL injection and Prepared statements using Paramters...right away...now; but what is the error - VS/VB told you more than 'error in SQL command'

Comment: just focus on my sql command, im trying to ask if my declaring where is correct. becuase thats my only problem.

Comment: I did focus on your SQL - that kind of error is much less likely using parameters; the code is less of a nightmare to read too.

Comment: connection closed? error in mysql statement?which error?

Comment: I edited my question please try to look, i just having problem with my where clause

Comment: SQL INSERT doesnt use a WHERE clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You havent said what the error is, it could be something to do with Disconnect, but I suspect it is a SQL syntax error because `INSERT` doesnt use a WHERE (you are inserting *new* data).

Here is a way to use params to make the code easier to read and avoid SQL injection attacks:

```
Dim SQL As String = "INSERT INTO alamnotice (correctivePreventive,
             sectionInCharge, shiftInCharge, SectionHead, status, 
             dateResponded, remarksSurrendingAlarm, Remarks) 
             VALUES ("@p1", "@p2", "@p3", "@p4", "@p5", "@p6", "@p7", "@p8")"

' I am assuming OleDB, but much the same for others
'    be sure to add the values in the same order with OleDB
Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQL, dbCon)
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtcorPrevAction.Text )
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", txtCause.Text)
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", cmbstatus.Text)
  ' etc

  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

for non string columns, such as a date, convert the textbox text:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pX", COnvert.ToInt32(txtSomeValue.Text))
```

the code is easier to read and if you arent gluing ticks and stuff into a string, there are far fewer string format errors like a missing `'`

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
UPDATE alamnotice SET correctivePreventive = '" & Trim(txtremarks.Text.TrimEnd()) & "'  WHERE controlNumber ='" & Trim(Form1.txtcontrolNumber.Text.TrimEnd()) & "'"
```