# Insert all data of a datagridview to database vb.net

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access

```
    Dim Con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Music_Sales_Database.mdb;")
    Dim Com As OleDbCommand
    Dim SaleCode As Integer
    Dim MusicID As String
    Dim SubTotalPrice As Decimal
    Dim Copies1 As Integer
    Dim STR1 As String

    SaleCode = 1

    Com = New OleDbCommand
    Com.Connection = Con

    For x As Integer = 0 To SalesDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
        MusicID = SalesDataGridView.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value
        SubTotalPrice = SalesDataGridView.Rows(x).Cells(5).Value
        Copies1 = SalesDataGridView.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value
        STR1 = "INSERT INTO Sales(Sales_ID, Sales_Date, Copies, Music_ID, Staff_ID, Total_Price) VALUES (@Sales_ID, @Sales_Date, @Copies, @Music_ID, @Staff_ID, @Total_Price)"
        Dim Comm As New OleDbCommand(STR1, Con)
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sales_ID", SaleCode)
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sales_Date", txtDateAndTime)
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Copies", Copies1)
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Music_ID", MusicID)
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Staff_ID", txtStaff_ID)
        Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_Price", SubTotalPrice)
        'Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Comm.Dispose()
    Next
    Connection.Close()
```

Hallo to all my senior, I don't know why it is no any error showing and can't save it in Access Database.

The whole code is in the button, I explain how I want my the program works:

1.) I have a unbound datagridview that can add data from few textbox.
2.) A button called Check - Out, this button is for passing my datagridview data to Access Database.....this is the problem I face.....Can somebody help me to solve it.....

Thx a lot...

I also referred to the this link, but I'm not too familiar with C# [Insert all data of a datagridview to database at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556556/insert-all-data-of-a-datagridview-to-database-at-once)

Comment: why is `Command.ExecuteNonQuery()` commented out?  that makes it do work.  Also, `Comm.Dispose()` should be outside the Next block to insert all rows.  Otherwise an explanation of how it fails, or any errors would be helpful.

Comment: @Plutonix it show "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when nvr comment out the Command.ExecuteQuery()

Comment: your OLEDBCommand object is created as `Com`; but you also create `Comm` then use `Command`.  you only need one OleDBCommand object, pick one.  Here is a sample of how to use USING blocks - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377408/how-can-i-use-where-function-using-insert-into-module/23377684#23377684

Answer (score 1):

You're making things more complex than they need to be.  Just create a `DataTable` and bind it to the grid.  When it comes time to save the data, it takes one call to the `Update` method of a data adapter to save the lot.  You use the same data adapter to generate the schema in the `DataTable` by calling `FillSchema` and then use a command builder to generate the `INSERT` command or you can build the schema and the `INSERT` command manually.  Here are some examples:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872-Retrieving-and-Saving-Data-in-Databases&highlight=

Answer (score 0):

you were required to open connection before the for loop and remove the comment at Command.ExecuteNonQuery()

your code will be as shown below

```
Dim Con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Music_Sales_Database.mdb;")
Dim Com As OleDbCommand
Dim SaleCode As Integer
Dim MusicID As String
Dim SubTotalPrice As Decimal
Dim Copies1 As Integer
Dim STR1 As String

SaleCode = 1

Com = New OleDbCommand
Com.Connection = Con
Connection.open()
For x As Integer = 0 To SalesDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
    MusicID = SalesDataGridView.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value
    SubTotalPrice = SalesDataGridView.Rows(x).Cells(5).Value
    Copies1 = SalesDataGridView.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value
    STR1 = "INSERT INTO Sales(Sales_ID, Sales_Date, Copies, Music_ID, Staff_ID, Total_Price) VALUES (@Sales_ID, @Sales_Date, @Copies, @Music_ID, @Staff_ID, @Total_Price)"
    Dim Comm As New OleDbCommand(STR1, Con)
    Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sales_ID", SaleCode)
    Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sales_Date", txtDateAndTime)
    Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Copies", Copies1)
    Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Music_ID", MusicID)
    Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Staff_ID", txtStaff_ID)
    Comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_Price", SubTotalPrice)
    Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Comm.Dispose()
Next
Connection.Close()
```