# Data type mismatch in criteria expression error visual basic

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to create a small database and I have it almost finished but I have one issue. I am trying to add all of the contents of my `DataGridView` to my database table. I keep getting an error: 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression.' Can anyone help me figure out why. I have been pulling my hair for the past week on this. Also, all contents of the database are deleted fine, but nothing is added because I get that error. Here is my code:

```
    Dim connect As New OleDbConnection
    connect.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=../Database.mdb")
    connect.Open()

    Dim str As String
    str = "DELETE * FROM Tickets"
    Dim cmdd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, connect)
    Try
        cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmdd.Dispose()

        Dim AssignedCSR, Network, TicketNumber, SeatName, AssetSerial, MACAddress, ClientName,
            Building, Room, Phone, PowerPack, Location, AdditionalDetails, ActiveDirectory, BaseImage,
            HibernationSettings, Install_CAE, Symantec, AddedToDomain, CAE_FULL_CONNECT, RemoveFreecell,
            VerifySW, VerifyEmail, EstablishConnection, AddedBy, Status1, Status2, Status3, Status4,
            Finished, ReturnedBy As String
        Dim DateReceived As Date
        For p As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            AssignedCSR = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
            Network = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
            TicketNumber = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(2).Value.ToString()
            DateReceived = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(3).Value.ToString()
            SeatName = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(4).Value.ToString()
            AssetSerial = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(5).Value.ToString()
            MACAddress = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(6).Value.ToString()
            ClientName = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(7).Value.ToString()
            Building = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(8).Value.ToString()
            Room = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(9).Value.ToString()
            Phone = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(10).Value.ToString()
            PowerPack = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(11).Value.ToString()
            Location = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(12).Value.ToString()
            AdditionalDetails = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(13).Value.ToString()
            ActiveDirectory = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(14).Value.ToString()
            BaseImage = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(15).Value.ToString()
            HibernationSettings = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(16).Value.ToString()
            Install_CAE = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(17).Value.ToString()
            Symantec = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(18).Value.ToString()
            AddedToDomain = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(19).Value.ToString()
            CAE_FULL_CONNECT = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(20).Value.ToString()
            RemoveFreecell = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(21).Value.ToString()
            VerifySW = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(22).Value.ToString()
            VerifyEmail = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(23).Value.ToString()
            EstablishConnection = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(24).Value.ToString()
            AddedBy = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(25).Value.ToString()
            Status1 = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(26).Value.ToString()
            Status2 = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(27).Value.ToString()
            Status3 = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(28).Value.ToString()
            Status4 = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(29).Value.ToString()
            Finished = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(30).Value.ToString()
            ReturnedBy = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(p).Cells(31).Value.ToString()

            str = "INSERT INTO Tickets(AssignedCSR,Network,TicketNumber,DateReceived,SeatName,AssetSerial," & _
                "MACAddress,ClientName,Building,Room,Phone,PowerPack,Location,AdditionalDetails,ActiveDirectory," & _
                "BaseImage,HibernationSettings,Install_CAE,Symantec,AddedToDomain,CAE_FULL_CONNECT,RemoveFreecell," & _
                "VerifySW,VerifyEmail,EstablishConnection,AddedBy,Status1,Status2,Status3,Status4,Finished,ReturnedBy) " & _
                "VALUES('" & AssignedCSR & "','" & Network & "','" & TicketNumber & "',#" & DateReceived & "#,'" &
                SeatName & "','" & AssetSerial & "','" & MACAddress & "','" & ClientName & "','" & Building & "','" &
                Room & "','" & Phone & "','" & PowerPack & "','" & Location & "','" & AdditionalDetails & "','" &
                ActiveDirectory & "','" & BaseImage & "','" & HibernationSettings & "','" & Install_CAE & "','" &
                Symantec & "','" & AddedToDomain & "','" & CAE_FULL_CONNECT & "','" & RemoveFreecell & "','" &
                VerifySW & "','" & VerifyEmail & "','" & EstablishConnection & "','" & AddedBy & "','" &
                Status1 & "','" & Status2 & "','" & Status3 & "','" & Status4 & "','" & Finished & "','" &
                ReturnedBy & "')"
            cmdd = New OleDbCommand(str, connect)
            cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmdd.Dispose()
        Next
        connect.Close()

        Dim i As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
        MsgBox("Ticket " & DataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value.ToString() & " was successfully updated!")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Okay, first issue I see immediately is adding it to a specific numbered cell. That's dangerous with this many columns You should loop through columns, or dynamically create columns to match your data. I'd bet money that you're trying to assign a string to a integer or etc because you mis numbered your stuff. Maybe do cell("ColumnName") instead?

Comment: Hell, it could be missing single quotes in that nightmare of a string concatenation

Comment: The *first* issue is that you are not using SQL parameters; then every single value is being passed as string (its *not* a universal type).  Then, look at the resulting `str` in debug and see if the SQL is well formed.  SQL params alone will improve readability as well as reduce data type conversions.  Finally, there are some db Object there not being disposed of.

Comment: If one of your string contains a ' you are screwed. Look at parameterized query.

Comment: @Plutonix, You have any tips on how to use SQL Parameters? I am not very familiar with SQL Parameters, sorry. Or is there any other way to add all of the contents in my `DataGridView` into my table?

Comment: @Plutonix would this link help me with SQL Parameters? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23772591/insert-all-data-of-a-datagridview-to-database-vb-net