# Trying to Insert Text to Access Database with ExecuteNonQueryin VB

Tags: vb.net, insert, executenonquery

I'm working on this feature were i save text from a textbox on my form to a access database file. With the click on my "store" button I want to save the text in the corresponding textbox fields to the fields in my access database for searching and retrieving purposes. Im doing this in VB

The problem I run into is the INSERT TO error with my "store" button
Any help or insight as to why im getting error would be greatly appreciated.

here is my code:

```
Dim con As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim cmd As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim dr As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader
Dim sqlStr As String

Private Sub btnStore_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStore.Click

    con = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Eric\Documents\SPC1.2.accdb")
    con.Open()

    MsgBox("Initialized")

    sqlStr = "INSERT INTO Master FADV Calll info  (First Name, Last Name, 
       Phone Number, Email, User Id) values (" & txtFirstName.Text & " ' ,'" &
       txtLastName.Text & "','" & txtPhone.Text & "', '" & txtEmail.Text & "', '" &
       txtUserID.Text & "', '" & txtOtherOptionTxt.Text & "','" 
       & txtCallDetail.Text & "');"

    cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlStr, con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()   <------- **IM RECIVING THE ERROR HERE** 
    MsgBox("Stored")
    ''pass ther parameter as sq; query, con " connection Obj)"

    con.Close()
```

---

So I tried to clean up my code a little, I didn't use paramerters like you recommended yet so maybe that is why I am still receiving the error. I figured this would work since it was a little cleaner

```
sqlStr = "INSERT INTO Master FADV Calll info(First Name, Last Name, Phone Number,
 Email, User Id,Notes) values (@First Name, @Last Name, @Phone Number,@ Email,
 @UserId,@Notes)"


    cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlStr, con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()'
```

Now by parameters do you mean something along the lines of this
'cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = FirstName'

---

im still getting this crazy error its making me want to bang my head against a wall. I do apologize for bugging you on such a meager issue, but please bear with me. I am receiving this error message here is my code
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '@First Name'.

but even before I was still getting an input error at the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() line.

'Dim SQL As String = "INSERT INTO [Master FADV Calll info] Values  (@First Name, @Last Name, @Phone Number,)"

```
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQL, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First Name", txtFirstName.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last Name", txtLastName.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone Number", txtPhone.Text)
        ' etc

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End Using'
```

---

I fianaly got it to work. here is my code

' con = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Eric\Documents\Fadv.accdb")
        con.Open()

```
    Dim SQL As String = "INSERT INTO [info] ([FirstName], [LastName], [Phone#]) Values (?, ?, ?)"


    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(Sql, con)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtFirstName.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", txtLastName.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", txtPhone.Text)
        ' etc

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        con.Close()
    End Using
```

'

Comment: you have mismatched ticks in your SQL string.  Use Parameters and that problem and much worse ones (see SQL injection) will disappear; as a free bonus, you code will be easier to read.  [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23377684/1070452)

Comment: may also be missing a JOIN in the SQL too if Master, FADV, Calll, info are tables

Comment: then it should be `[Master FADV Calll info]`

Comment: a) if there are spaces in teh table name, you need to escape them with `[...]`  b) escape the column names too since they have spaces c) the link in the first comment shows how to do Parameters with OleDb  you use '?' in the SQL and "@p...` in the param.  With spaces in the names, the SQL processor cant tell where the names start or end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mismatched ticks are a big problem when concatenating strings to get a SQL statement.  A bigger problem is the threat of SQL injection attacks.  You also have some very strange table and column names - names with spaces in them must be "escaped" using brackets:

`Master FADV Calll info`   ==>  `[Master FADV Calll info]`

```
con = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Eric\Documents\SPC1.2.accdb")
con.Open()

Dim SQL As String = "INSERT INTO [Master FADV Calll info] ([First Name], 
        [Last Name], [Phone Number], Email, [User Id], Notes ) 
        Values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQL, Con)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtFirstName.Text )
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", txtLastName.Text)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", txtPhone.Text)
   ' etc

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
End Using
```

In OleDB parameters are positional (only), so you have to add the parameter values in the same order as the columns are listed in the SQL.

Using parameters

- you avoid [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)
- less chance of botching the SQL from missing ticks `'`
- code is easier to read and maintain

Comment: hey plutonix your so Awesome your technique made everything so uniform, but im still getting this crazy error its making me want to bang my head against a wall. I do apologize for bugging you on such a meager issue, but please bear with me.

Comment: @user3673701 I missed something in the post but it is mentioned in the comment above: you have to specify column names, but if you have spaces in them, you need to escape them with `[...]`.  Thus, `[First Name]` but only `Email` or `Notes`.  You **must** add the values with AddWithValue in the same order as those names appear.  Also if a column is not Text/string, you must convert your TextBox.Text like this `AddWithValue("@pN", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox.Text))`. Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a tick after the value and paren...

```
 Values('" &
```

Put that in and see if it works... Also as Plutonix has mentioned, use parameterized queries; better approach overall.