# How to insert the values of 3 droplists into a single column of an MS Access database, using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access-2007

In my project i display an 3 droplists (`Daydrplist`, `MonthDropList`, `YearDropList`). When the user selects the values and clicks the button the values should be inserted to the access database in the `BirthDate` column of the `Teacher` table.

How can I do that?

```
Protected Sub NextBtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles NextBtn.Click

    con = New OleDbConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\user\Desktop\web programming\\IULWebInformationSystem1\IULWebInformationSystem1\App_Data\IUlDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=True"
    con.Open()
    sqlquery = "insert into Teacher values ('" & FirstNameTxtBox.Text & "','" & MiddelNameTxtBox.Text & "','" & LastNameTxtBox.Text & "','" & POBTxtBox.Text & "','" & NationalityDropList.SelectedValue & "','" & Gendrplist.SelectedValue & "')"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlquery, con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    FirstNameTxtBox.Text = ""
    MiddelNameTxtBox.Text = ""
    LastNameTxtBox.Text = ""
    POBTxtBox.Text = ""
    NationalityDropList.SelectedValue = ""
    Gendrplist.SelectedValue = ""




    lblmsg2.Text = "Personal Information was Added Successfully"
    lblmsg2.Visible = True

    Response.Redirect("PersonalAddress.aspx")


End Sub
```

Comment: you can achieve this by concatenating them using comma and than insert into database

Comment: a) SQL is incorrect specify columns/order  b) use SQL parameters (always) rather than concatenating strings  c) date values should be dates - rather than 3 text dropdowns, consider a DateTimePicker d) [This example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23377684/1070452) shows how to do most of this

Comment: thank u for you advice , i have another problem in the drop list i need to insert the value selected from droplist into the access database but i didn't know how the data wasn't inserted when i click the button